# Prove the equality of the following problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} i^2 = (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n i$$
for all integers $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We condemn uploading pictures, you should try to write your problem using LaTeX. Here is your LaTeX guide: https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols
Also please write whatever you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: This seems like a good place to use induction.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: I would suggest trying a few to see if you get a feel and maybe even an intuition as to why it would be: $n-1:  1 = 1$, $n=2:  1-4=-(1+2)$, $n=3: 1-4+9 = (1+2+3)$ and $n=4: 1-4+9-16 = -(1+2+3+4)$.  Are you seeing any patterns? Any reason to see why it may be true?  It seems like when you have $n^2$ and you subtract $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i$ you will end up with $\sum_{i=1}^n i$.  Why do you think that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=2m$, then
$$\sum_{1}^{2m} (-1)^{k-1}*k^2=-\sum_{k=1}^m (4k-1)=-4\frac{m(m+1)}{2}-m=-m(2m+1)=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k.$$
Next, take $n=2m+1$. then

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1}(-1)^{k-1} k^2=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}(-1)^{k-1} k^2+(2m+1)^2=-m(2m+1)+4m^2+4m+1=2m^2+3m+1=(2m+1)(m+1)=\frac{(2m+1)(2m+2)}{2}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$$